# Hidding the UIButtons

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I ve created the 8 buttons dynamically.I want to add all these buttons to an array.... I use this code.. It all works fine..But in another method I want hide all the dynamic butttons..Here the problem arises....
Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *button=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setTag:i];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 108, 150);
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            xpos +=300;
            x+=194;
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                ypos+=188;
                xpos=160;
            }
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
            [button addObject:btn];

        }
    }

-(void)hidebutton{
     for(int i=0;i<[button count];i++)
    {
        NSObject *obj=[button objectAtIndex:i];
    }
    )
```

Here I can't use the property `obj.Hidden=YES;` How can I achieve tis? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you getting the buttons on view?

Comment: Do you see the buttons in your view?

Comment: Your code is correct and array has 8 buttons. How you print it to console?

Comment: nslog(@"%@",button); tis is the way i print......

Comment: this is not the right way to see the elements of the array...As you have buttons in array first check the count... NSLog(@"%d"[button count]); See if it is 8 or 0...

Comment: `Hidden` is not a property. `hidden` is however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSObject doesn't have a hidden-property. Make sure you typecast it to one that has.

If there are only UIButtons in that array of yours change it to this:

```
UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)[button objectAtIndex:i];
[aButton setHidden:YES];
```

---

Editted due comment:

If you want to hide your button on buttonpress you should call the method you added to every button as target. This method passes along the sender which is in fact the very button that was clicked upon. This is why you put the ":" behind de buttonPressed:-method.

To hide any of your buttons on buttonpress it will look something like this.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [aButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

This should work for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for ur code.... If I want to hide my button in some other method...Do u thnk am I following the correct method??

Comment: What you are doing is not really a problem. If you want to hide the button as soon as you click on it though you should use the buttonClicked: method which you added as target to every button.
In that method you are sending along with your method the sender. Which is in fact the button that was clicked on.

In this case you should adjust my above code a bit and typecast the sender to UIButton then so the very same thing. I will add this to my above answer.